# Accessing a class variable in another class shows a different behavior in C++

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++. Here in my case I have created two classes, `class One` and `class Two`. `_x` is declared as a *private* member variable of `class One`. So here I am trying to learn different methods to access this *private* variable(`_x`) from any other class(Here in this case it is `class Two`). This is my scenario basically. So one method I tried is ,making `class Two` as a `friend class` of `class One` and for accessing this variable, I have used `directValOfOne` function to print the value of this variable and another one I tried was passing the address of the `class One` instance in another member function (`getDataTwo`) of `class Two`. Everything works well until here.

As you can see, I have initialized the `_x` using a parameterized constructor and printing this variable gives me the value as `10` using both the methods. Again I modified this variable using a
setter function (`setDataOne`) to `220` and when I print it using the `getDataTwo` function it prints the value as `220`. But when I tried to print the value using  `directValOfOne`, it still showing the old initialized value (`10`) which I am really confused. I have printed the address of `class One` object in this `directValOfOne` funtion and it shows same. If so then why the new value(`220`) is not updated here.

Source code is placed below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class One{
    int _x;
public:
    One(int a):_x{a} {}
    //setters and getters
    void setDataOne(int a) { _x = a; }
    int getDataOne() const { return _x; }
    //print values
    void printOne() { cout<<"_x - "<<_x<<endl; }
    friend class Two;
};

class Two{
    One _a;
    int id_one = 0;
public:
    Two(One a):_a{a} {}
    //setters and getters
    void setDataTwo(int a) {  }
    int getDataTwo(One *obj) {
        id_one = obj->getDataOne();
        return id_one;
    }
    void printTwo() { printf("id_one = %d\n",id_one); }
    void directValOfOne() {
        printf("address  = %p\n",&_a);
        printf("_a._x = %d\n",_a._x);
    }
};

int main(){
    One one(10);
    Two two(one);
    one.printOne();
    two.getDataTwo(&one);
    two.printTwo();
    two.directValOfOne();
    printf(" *********** \n");
    one.setDataOne(222);
    one.printOne();
    two.getDataTwo(&one);
    two.printTwo();
    two.directValOfOne();

    return 0;
}
```

and the console output is,

> ```
> _x - 10
> id_one = 10
> address  = 006dfee4
> _a._x = 10
>  ***********
> _x - 222
> id_one = 222
> address  = 006dfee4
> _a._x = 10
> ```

As you can see the `_a._x` still prints the value `10`. But actually the `_x` is updated to new value `220`. Sorry if I explained it so detail. Just to give you an overview I detailed like this.

So my que is ,

> Why it is not showing the updated value since the addresses are same?

> Am I missing any important concept here ? If so please guide me to understand this problem.

Comment: `One _a;` is a member of `Two`, and it's that members `_x` that is being printed with the last call in `main`. That member is never changed in this code after construction of `two`, which was given a `One` holding a value of `10`, to store by-copy.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig. +1 for this . The store by-copy was the issue. Now its clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you pass to `Two` an instance of class `One` **by value**. This means that `Two` stores a copy of the instance of `One` you pass to it. When you change the value of `_x` in `one` it does not affect the value of `_x` in `_a` (inside `two`).

In order for your code to work you need to pass a reference to `One` in `Two`'s constructor and store this reference. Now every change to `one` will also affect `_a`.

Modified code:

```
class Two{
    One& _a;
    int id_one = 0;
public:
    Two(One& a):_a(a) {}
    // ...
```

Regarding the address issue, the address of `_a` will stay the same since there's no reason for it to change once initialized. If you'll print the address of `one` **in your current code** (before the suggested modifications) it should be in a different address than `_a` (since `_a` is a copy that's located somewhere else).

**In the modified version of the code** you should see the same address since it's the same object.

Comment: Ohh you cracked it. Thanks Gal for the explanation. +1 for this :-).  But I still have the confusion of that address part. What do you mean by "print the address of `one` **in your current code** " ? What sort of modification I need to do in my code. Could you please elaborate in your answer itself.

Comment: @VishnuCS If you print the address of `one` in main, you'll see it is different from the address printed from inside `two` when it prints the address of _a (because they are two different objects.)